# Ruby Rails 3.2.x - How to find the UTF-8 character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I dont know how this happened, but most likely I must have accidentally added a UTF-8 character into one of the many files, whenever I now start

```
rails s
```

I get the error:

```
[2013-04-19 21:56:34] ERROR Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xAD" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:58:in `write'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:58:in `<<'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:58:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:133:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:71:in `error'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:98:in `rescue in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:113:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

How do I find the file that is causing this?

I already added # encoding: UTF-8  to each of the locales files. So it isn't them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened here, I ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo update-locale
```

restarted the web server and everything was back to normal. Very very weird what happened here. The error came out of nowhere.